# Automated/unit testing of Vbscript

Tags: testing, vbscript, automated-tests

I have a program with a COM API. I have a suite of functional tests using Python, but I want to provide a suite of VBscript code samples, and I'd like to test this suite of code automatically.

Is there a tool I can use to run a suite of VBscript tests without interaction, and collect pass/fail and timing statistics?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found a test runner for vbscript, [ScriptUnit](http://www.xt1.org/scriptunit).

It can be run without the GUI using the /Q option, so it looks like this one will fit the bill.

[image]